# uBLAS matrix clear memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, matrix, boost-ublas

I have a uBLAS matrix, like so:

```
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> mat(50000,50000);
```

Once I'm done with a set of calculations on the matrix, I want its memory freed.

I have been using `mat.clear()` which, according to the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm), "clears the matrix". But my program keeps running out of memory.

Digging into the headers, I find this:

```
void clear () {
  std::fill (data ().begin (), data ().end (), value_type/*zero*/());
}
```

So there's a clear semantics problem with `clear()`.

The question then is, how do I ensure that the memory is freed?

Comment: Do you happen to have found a solution to the problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I seem to be running into he same issue. 

An in-elegant way of handling the issue would be resizing the matrix to (0,0). I was wondering if there is a "right" way to do it.

Comment: @Devil, but is resizing guaranteed to release memory? For instance, with `std::vector` a resize does not make such a guarantee since the vector may be enlarged again later and allocations are expensive. Instead, the C++11 `shrink_to_fit()` function must be used. I never did find an adequate solution to this problem and eventually switched to using an std::vector of std::vectors since I mostly wanted uBLAS as a handy 2d matrix.

Comment: Unfortunately Ublas uses clear with a different semantic compared to the STL. Spying the code it seems resize(0, 0, false) will de-allocate its memory. To be sure one can also use std::vector as array type and invoke shrink_to_fit() on data() after resize(0, 0, false).

Answer (score 0):

An inelegant way to return the memory is by resizing the matrix:

```
mat.resize(0,0,false);
```

Though I have not tried using zero for a size value myself...